# sending email with smtp client with attachment giving error

Tags: c#, smtpclient

i am sending an attachement, and the email sends successfuly , but when i tries to delete the same file it gives the error as "file is being used by another process"
i am deleting by system.io.file.delete()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you `Dispose` correctly? For both the `Stream` and the `SmtpClient` after sending the mail?

Comment: not infact smtpclient havnt any dispose function
and Stream is not used while sending the attachment, just using MailMessage and smtpclient

Comment: @vakas: But both `MailMessage` and `AttachmentBase` do have `Dispose` methods, so it's still a valid suggestion.

Comment: @vakas: So how do you add the attachment?